# Views - Rewrite Results doesn't work

Tags: views

i have three field to show in views: title,body,desc.
in desc
I choose rewrite results and then put those
[title]
[body]
but nothing shows up. i used inspect element by chrome, desc is here but empty.

Comment: Try adding a field `Global: Custom text` at the end of your field list, add the replacement patterns in the `Text' box, and see if it works.

Comment: Just check is there any value in desc field. If desc field is empty then output will be empty only. Your rewriting based on that desc field, if it is empty then empty output will return.

Answer (score 1):

Add a field `Global: Custom text` at the end of your field list, add the replacement patterns in the `Text' box.

The is from the comment by Dom Day which worked for me.
Still wondering why the method in the question produced no output at all.